# Is there anyway to 'return false' in a short circuit for Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What I want is like this, `A && B && (return false)`.

I can do assignment, logical calculation, calling a method or invoking a function, but just can't return false.

I know that using `if` then everything is ok, and just wanna know whether short circuit can do it.

I've tried `eval('return false')`,but got an error,`Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement`.

Anyone can help me?

**Upadte :**

Well, what I want is just to replace

```
if(A)
    if(B)
        C;
```

with

```
A && B && C;
```

But if `C` is `return false` , I got an error.I don't know why.And now I think `if else` is easier to use and understand, so I'll try it later on. And thanks for all guys commented and answered.

Comment: you might as well get rid of `A && B &&` and just have false?

Comment: What's the point of attempting to do this? It would just result in bizarre code. Why can't you just do `if(A && B) { return false; }`?

Comment: either use **A && B && false** or **A && B && {return false;}**

Comment: `eval('return false')` throws an error because it is evaluated as a single statement in a new (essentially global) execution context where `return` can only occur in a function context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can simply:

```
return !(A && B)
```

You want to return `false` only if `A` and `B` evaluate to `true`, so there you have it.  Now, if you don't necessarily want to return right there at all times, then you're left with:

```
if(A && B) return false;
// more code
```

Aside from being impossible due to the basic rules of the language, what you want would make your code slightly harder to understand without providing any benefit.  Trust me, this way is better.

Comment: Yeah, I always want to put all codes in a single line via `|| &&`, rather than nesting `if(){}else{}`. It's cleaner, while really a bit harder to understand. I'll try `if(){}else{}` later on.Clearer codes may be better than cleaner codes.

Comment: @Fly_pig: It's really not cleaner.  I don't mean this to be rude, but trying to fit as much as possible on one line is typically a beginner thing.  As you gain experience you realize that it buys you nothing and only makes your code harder to maintain.